# need to create a temporary table inside my procedure which has a cursor in it

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

Procedure code below ::  TYPE line has errors while compilation.let me the know the correct usage of table creation here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bulk_order_export 
    (
        startdate IN       varchar2,
        enddate   IN       varchar2,
           batchsize  IN       varchar2
    )   
    IS
      bulkorderdata_cursor sys_refcursor ;
      p_query_string  VARCHAR2(100);
     TYPE FBL_BACKUP_ORDER IS TABLE OF DPS_USER%TYPE;
      temp_order_id FBL_BACKUP_ORDER;
    BEGIN

    p_query_string := 'SELECT ID FROM abc_order WHERE REGISTRATION_DATE BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate'; 
    OPEN bulkorderdata_cursor FOR p_query_string USING startdate, enddate;
    LOOP
        FETCH bulkorderdata_cursor BULK COLLECT into temp_order_id LIMIT batchsize;  
    FORALL i IN 1..temp_order_id.count
            INSERT INTO FBL_BACKUP_ORDER VALUES(temp_order_id(i));   
    --COMMIT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Commit '||temp_order_id.count||' inserted rows');
     Total := Total+temp_order_id.count;
     EXIT WHEN bulkorderdata_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE bulkorderdata_cursor;
    END;
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi I am using oracle

Comment: Problem is I am not able to decalre a temp table to which i can insert  the bulk collected rows through cursor.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: FBL_BACKUP_ORDER is a **user defined type**. You cannot insert into it because **it is not a table**. You use it correctly when you declare a variable - `temp_order_id`. That variable is a temporary table - (well, an in-memory collection) and you're populating it properly. So what do you want to do next? Insert into DPS_USER?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to DPS_USER%TYPE, I assume that is a table? If so, then the syntax is: DPS_USER%ROWTYPE.

Then you need to make sure your variables are defined, batchsize is numeric, and then you have sorted out some syntax, and you'll be good to go

```
SQL> create table DPS_USER ( id int );

Table created.

SQL> create table abc_order ( id int );

Table created.

SQL> create table FBL_BACKUP_ORDER ( id int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bulk_order_export
  2      (
  3          startdate IN       varchar2,
  4          enddate   IN       varchar2,
  5             batchsize  IN    int
  6      )
  7      IS
  8        bulkorderdata_cursor sys_refcursor ;
  9        p_query_string  VARCHAR2(100);
 10       TYPE FBL_BACKUP_ORDER IS TABLE OF DPS_USER%ROWTYPE;
 11        temp_order_id FBL_BACKUP_ORDER;
 12        total int;
 13      BEGIN
 14
 15      p_query_string := 'SELECT ID FROM abc_order WHERE REGISTRATION_DATE BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate';
 16      OPEN bulkorderdata_cursor FOR p_query_string USING startdate, enddate;
 17      LOOP
 18          FETCH bulkorderdata_cursor BULK COLLECT into temp_order_id LIMIT batchsize;
 19      FORALL i IN 1..temp_order_id.count
 20              INSERT INTO FBL_BACKUP_ORDER VALUES temp_order_id(i);
 21      --COMMIT;
 22          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Commit '||temp_order_id.count||' inserted rows');
 23       Total := Total+temp_order_id.count;
 24       EXIT WHEN bulkorderdata_cursor%NOTFOUND;
 25      END LOOP;
 26      CLOSE bulkorderdata_cursor;
 27      END;
 28  /

Procedure created.
```